# NetSuite Client Script fieldChanged using old item values

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I made a simple client script following this logic: Once a new item is added or an item is changed to a new item, the Gross Margin will be auto calculated and added to the corresponding field for that item. The problem I am having is that fieldChanged is giving me the old (or undef.) sublist values for that item as if it hadn't changed yet. Is there a way to tell NetSuite to, after the item is changed, wait for its corresponding sublist values to update before populating the values with fieldChanged? Thanks!

```
function fieldChanged(context) {
    var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;
    var sublistName = context.sublistId;
    var sublistFieldName = context.fieldId;
    var line = context.line;

    if (sublistName === 'item' && sublistFieldName === 'item'){
        var costrateestimate = currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: sublistName,fieldId: 'costestimaterate'});
        var amount = currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: sublistName,fieldId: 'amount'});
        var quantity = currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: sublistName,fieldId: 'quantity'});
        var grossPerc = Math.round((1-(costrateestimate/amount*quantity))*100);

        log.debug("Gross Margin Calculated = 100 - ("+costrateestimate+" / "+amount+" * "+currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: sublistName,fieldId: 'quantity'})+") = "+grossPerc+"%");

        currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: sublistName,
            fieldId: 'custcol_gross_margin_perc',
            value: grossPerc
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! I needed to use the postSourcing entry point instead of fieldChanged...